# No emulator after building Android kernel

Tags: android, android-emulator, compilation, kernel, javac

I followed the directions from http://source.android.com/source/building.html. However once I get to "Emulate an Android Device" section, there is no "emulator".

During the build, I got Killed messages:

> /bin/bash: line 1:  5372 Killed                  javac -J-Xmx512M -target 1.5 -Xmaxerrs >9999999 -encoding ascii -g -classpath out/host/linux-x86/framework/dx.jar:out
>   /host/linux->x86>/framework/dasm.jar:out/host/linux-x86/framework/cfassembler.jar:/usr/lib
>   /jvm/java-1.5.0>-sun/lib/tools.jar -extdirs "" -d out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES
>   /cts-dalvik-buildutil_intermediates/classes \@out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/cts-dalvik-
>   buildutil_intermediates/java-source-list-uniq
>   make: *** [out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/cts-dalvik-buildutil_intermediates/javalib.jar] Killed

This is the first javac command that follows the C++ compilations.
I've retried it multiple times without success.

Comment: How much memory does your computer have? It looks as though you may be running out during the compile.

Comment: I'm running this on a VM with 1GB of memory. How much do you recommend?

Comment: As much as you can stand to give it. The more, the better. Exact numbers depend on what you're running on the VM other than the build.

Comment: This time I got it to build, but there is still no 'emulator'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resulted from paths not being properly exported.
I followed this link: http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/07/envsetup-setpaths-and-the-emulator-avd-error/

and set ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT=/out/target/product/generic/
and also emulator is located at out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator